# Chrome extension - How a sandboxed page access data from storage?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When user click the extension icon, it opens a sandboxed new page in new tab. From the page, I want to access data from storage. Didn't find any useful info from official doc, please enlighten me.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
      "scripts": [
        "background.js"
      ],
      "persistent": true
    },
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_title": "My extension"
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "storage", "<all_urls>"],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
    "sandbox": {
      "pages": ["newtab.html"]
    }
  }
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: chrome.extension.getURL("newtab.html"),
    })
});
```

newtab.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body
</html>
```

app.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  // access data from storage
})
```

The reason I'm using a sandbox page, is because Im using Vue.js which needs to use  `eval`.

Comment: 1) you can declare a different file as a sandboxed page and put it into an iframe, then use DOM messaging via postMessage e.g. iframeElement.contentWindow.postMessage - your main page will have access to chrome storage and it'll provide the data to the iframe or 2) allow `eval` via [CSP key](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_security_policy).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for your reply! I removed "sandbox" entry from manifest.json, it's weird that the CSP "unsafe-eval" directive works now.